# Wagner dielectric dispersion derivation

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, dielectric, dispersion

In Wagner's work (https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01657322), he derived formulas for the apparent conductivity and permittivity of the spherical particles suspended in medium. He showed that potential at a great distance from a single particle equals:
$$
    \varphi = E_{0}\left( r + \frac{R^{3}}{r^{2}}\frac{\Lambda_{2}-\Lambda_{1}}{2\Lambda_{2}+\Lambda_{1}} \right)\cos\vartheta
$$
Then he stated, that if there are $m$ of such particles and they do not interact with each other, the potential at great distance will be:
$$
    \varphi = E_{0}\left( r + \frac{\boldsymbol{m}R^{3}}{r^{2}}\frac{\Lambda_{2}-\Lambda_{1}}{2\Lambda_{2}+\Lambda_{1}} \right)\cos\vartheta
$$
How can one come to this conclusion? What are the properties and thought process involved? Is it simple summation of the particle related terms? I can't see that from the general Laplace equation solution.

Comment: I don't have an access to article, but it seems to me that electric potential is proportional to particle volume, which in many-particles system becomes a total volume of all particles. But this is just my guess.